# How to extract nodes that occur as both subject and object in a graph?

Tags: rdf, sparql

I want to retrieve a list of nodes(vertices in the graph) that occur both in the subject and object part of a triple(not necessarily the same triple).

I tried doing it using a sub query as follows:

```
SELECT ?x
{

       ?x ?p ?o.

     {
         SELECT ?x  WHERE { ?s ?p ?x . }
     }
}
```

It is not giving me the exact results in the sense I am getting multiple instances of the node instance. And when I tried DISTINCT, it gave even more instances for some reason.

On a side note, if I wanted to extract the nodes that are subject OR object, how should I go about doing that?

Please excuse if there are any mistakes in the vocabulary used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Nodes that are subjects and objects

#### Short and sweet

Just ask for something that appears as a subject and an object:

```
select distinct ?x {
  ?s1 ?p1  ?x .
   ?x ?p2 ?o2 .
}
```

#### Making it illegible (just for fun)

If you want to make that a bit shorter, but much less readable, you can use something like

```
prefix : <...anything...>

select distinct ?x {
  ?x (:|!:) ?o ; ^(:|!:) ?s .
}
```

The pattern `(:|!:)` matches any property that is either `:` or not `:`. That means it matches everything;  it's just a wildcard. (You could just use `?p` which is essentially a wildcard, too, but keep reading…)  The path `^p` means p, but in the reverse direction (so, e.g., `?person foaf:name ?name` and `?name ^foaf:name ?person` match the same data.  Since `(:|!:)` is a wildcard, `^(:|!:)` is a wildcard in the reverse direction.  We can't use variables in property paths, so even though `?p` is a "forward wildcard", we can't use `^?p` as a "backward wildcard". The `;` notation just lets you abbreviate, e.g., `?x :p2 :o1` and `?x :p2 :o2` as `?x :p1 :o1 ; :p2 :o2`.  Using it here, we can get:

```
?x  (:|!:) ?o ;    # every ?x that is a subject
   ^(:|!:) ?s .    # every ?x that is an object
```

Removing comments and linebreaks, we get

```
?x (:|!:) ?o ; ^(:|!:) ?s .
```

You should probably use the readable one. :)

### Nodes that are subjects or objects

This was already answered in your previous question about computing node degree, [How to calculate maximum degree of a directed graph using SPARQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24270532/1281433).  The answer there used this query to compute degree:

```
select ?x (count(*) as ?degree) { 
  { ?x ?p ?o } union
  { ?s ?p ?x }
}
group by ?x
```

It can find nodes that are subjects or objects, too, though.  Just change it to:

```
select distinct ?x  { 
  { ?x ?p ?o } union
  { ?s ?p ?x }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a wildcard approach here, too:

```
select distinct ?x {
  ?x (:|!:)|^(:|!:) [].
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why 
select distinct ?x {
  ?s1 ?p1 ?x .
   ?x ?p1 ?o1.
}

won't yield the result I was looking for? 

As usual, your answer is spot on! Thanks :)

Comment: You're using `?p1` twice, which means that you're only counting those `?x`s that are a subject and object of the same property.  It won't let you match, e.g., `:a` in data like `:a :p :b . :c :q :a`.  `:a` is a subject and object there, but not with the same property.